# Geometry proof for proving two triangles are congruent

Tags: geometry

[image]

**Given:** $\angle A \cong \angle 3$

$\angle C \cong \angle 4$

$ \overline{\rm DB}$ bisects $\angle ADC$

$ \overline{\rm AD} \cong \overline{\rm DC}$

Prove by any method $\triangle ADB \cong \triangle CDB$

**Proof:**

I was thinking of proving this by using SAS since $AD\cong DC$ and we have that $\angle 3 = \angle 4$ since  $DB$ bisects $\angle ADC$. And then we have $DB=DB$ because of the reflexive property. Is this correct?

I'm a little confused because I don't know what the relevance of $\angle A \cong \angle 3$ and $\angle C \cong \angle 4$ is.

Comment: are you given that $DB$ bisects angle $ADC$? the part about the reflexive property is correct.

Comment: yes im sorry i forgot to add that to the givens. but yea i am given that $DB$ bisects $\angle ADC$

Comment: I wanna say they meant for you to use $ASA$ as angle $A$ is congruent to angle $C$. And angle $3$ is congruent to angle $4$. Angle $A$ is congruent to angle $C$ as angle $3$ is congruent to angle $4$ and congruence is transitive.

Comment: "I was thinking of proving this by using SAS since AD≅DC and we have that ∠3=∠4 since DB bisects ∠ADC. And then we have DB=DB because of the reflexive property. Is this correct?"  Yes.  That is correct and you are completely done.  "I don't know what the relevance of ∠A≅∠3 and ∠C≅∠4 is."  The question is by *any* method.  You can leave out nearly any two of the conditions and still prove it but some other method.  I think the point of this excercise was to let the student develop their chops be any means that works for them.

Comment: Note you can go further and prove $m\angle A =m\angle C=m\angle 3=m\angle 4 = 45^{\circ}$ and $AB= DB=CB$ and $m\angle ABD=m\angle CBD=90^{\circ}$ and $AD=DC = \sqrt 2AB$ and $\triangle ABD \cong \triangle CBD$ and  $\triangle ABD \sim \triangle CBD\sim \triangle ADC$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea was more of a "creative writing" excercise to get the student comfortable with think for themselves and approaching a problem with an "I don't know the answer but I think I can analyze it".

The question says bey *any* method and there are plenty.  I can use $AD =DC$ to show the triangle is isoceles and therefore we have $\angle 3= \angle A =\angle C$ and $AD = AD$ and $\angle A=\angle C =\angle 4$ so we get it by $SAS$ in another way.

Or we could forget that $AC=AD$ and get that $DB$ bisects$\angle ADC$ so $\angle A =\angle 3=\angle 4 = \angle C$ and you can do $SAS$ the way you did.

Or you could not the triangle are iscoseles due to the angles and conclude that $AB=BC =DB$ and $DB$ is the perpendicular bisector and ....

Basically, you are just expected to develop your chops anyway you see fit.

Comment: ah okay thank you, so my answer is still correct right?

Comment: Of course, your answer is correct.  SAS.... a classic.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\angle A=\angle3$ and $\angle C=\angle4$, we have$\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle CBD$ are isosceles with $\overline{AB}=\overline{BD}=\overline{BC}$. And we have one more pair of edges $\overline{AD}=\overline{DC}$, we can use $SSS$. Indeed, there are more conditions given than needed.

Answer (score 0):

If $DB$ bisects $\angle ADC$, then since$$\angle A=\angle 3=\angle 4=\angle C$$it follows that$$\angle 1=\angle 2$$making DB the perpendicular bisector of $AC$, and by SAS$$\triangle DBA\cong\triangle DBC$$

[Note: this does not need the given that $AD=DC$.]